# Saving output into a variable, viewing output live

Tags: bash, pipe, interactive

I'm trying to run a command and save the output of it into a variable (so I can later parse this and extract information from the output). I know how to save it into a variable but I would like it to show the output as it is coming, not only at the end, so I can see the output as it is being performed. Or even better, be able to both show it, and filter/execute other commands using that information.

I thought I could somehow pipe the command into `read`, but couldn't get it to work.

Here's the example code I've been using:

```
#!/bin/bash

count=0
function theloop() {
        while [ $count -lt 10 ]; do
                echo "the count is $count"
                sleep 1
                let count=count+1
        done
}

output=$(theloop)

echo "the output was:"
echo "$output"
```

This outputs the count, but only updates at the end, not writing a line every second.

Can someone tell me how to pipe theloop into `read`, or another solution. Even just saving it into a variable which I can parse later would be good, just so long as the screen is updated every second as the count is being generated.

I think I could somehow use `tee` into a temporary file, then read that, however that seems like an inelegant solution to me.

Edit: I should mention that I am planning to use this on the output from another program that I'm not smart enough to edit, so I would rather answers that do not change `theloop()` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `tee`ing the output into a temporary file you could `tee` it to `/dev/tty`.  Say

```
output=$(theloop | tee /dev/tty)
```

instead of

```
output=$(theloop)
```

and you'd get the output into a variable while it's being displayed.

---

EDIT: As per your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19873376/saving-output-into-a-variable-viewing-output-live/19873479?noredirect=1#comment29562081_19873479), if you want to only display count 7 to the console but keep all the output into the variable, you could say:

```
count=0
function theloop() {
        while [ $count -lt 10 ]; do
                [ $count -eq 7 ] && { echo "the count is $count" | tee /dev/tty; } || echo "the count is $count"
                sleep 1
                let count=count+1
        done
}

output=$(theloop)

echo "the output was:"
echo "$output"
```

Note that `tee` has now been moved inside the function.  Essentially, you `tee` conditionally, while continuing to `echo` everything.

If you can't change the function, you can say:

```
while read -r line; do
  output+="${line}\n"
  [[ $line == *7* ]] && echo ${line}
done < <(theloop)

echo "the output was:"
echo -e "${output}"
```

Comment: Cool idea. That worked. Any idea how I could then add say a `grep` or `if` to, say, filter it so I only saw count number 7 to the console but it still stored the whole thing in the `output` variable?

Comment: Sorry to make trouble, but that won't help me in my situation. The problem is that in reality I'm using the output from another program which I don't have control over. The `theloop()` function was just an example. Any way to do it without editing `theloop()`?

Comment: @localhost in future you should mention important things like this in the question at the outset.

Comment: Awesome, that looks like exactly what I want!! Thanks! What is that called, the `done < <(theloop)` part, so I can look it up?

Comment: @localhost Good to know that it worked for you.  `<(theloop)` is called [process substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Process-Substitution).  In future, please attempt to put as much information in your question rather than revealing stuff later.  It helps those who are trying to help!

Comment: @devnull yeah, I tried to think of everything when I wrote the question, but didn't think of that.

Comment: @devnull question has been edited to add the constraint of not editing `theloop()` function.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't use a temporary file, but a temporary named pipe (fifo), which consumes no disk space (also, I create it on a ramdisk, so it doesn't even touch the disk).

```
#!/bin/bash

count=0
function theloop() {
        while [ $count -lt 10 ]; do
                echo "the count is $count"
                sleep 1
                let count=count+1
        done
}

fifo=/dev/shm/foo
rm -f $fifo
mkfifo $fifo
cat <$fifo & output=$(theloop|tee $fifo)
rm $fifo

echo "the output was:"
echo "$output"
```

Comment: Any way to filter the output going to the console (say to only show count 7) while still saving the whole output into the variable?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you say it already. Why not pipe the output into read, like this:

`theloop | while read line; do echo $line and do something with it;done`

Note, however, that you may have problems setting variables within the read-loop such that they can be seen after the loop, because the part after the pipe symbol runs in a subshell.

Comment: Thanks. How would I get around these problems? That's exactly what I'd like to do, I'd like to just show say count number 7 on the console but still store the entire count in the `output` variable.

Comment: If you declare the variable outside the subshell, I think it would be visible outside the subshell afterwards.

Comment: Don't think so, I just tried it. Declared `output=""` first, but it is empty at the end when back outside the `while read line` loop. I think it creates another `output` variable in the subshell. :-(